# Python script hangs after entering username to remote login into a device using telnetlib

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to login to my network power control switch and run commands in it using python telnetlib script, after running the script it displays "enter the username" in the output terminal for which i enter the switch username and the script hangs at that point without asking for password and proceeding further.
kindly help me in proceeding further ..pasted the script below.

```
import getpass
import sys
import telnetlib
HOST = "192.168.8.8"
PORT=22 
TIMEOUT=10
user = input("Enter your username : ")
password = getpass.getpass()
tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST)
tn.read_until(b"User Name : ")
tn.write(user.encode('ascii') + b"\n")
if password:
    tn.read_until(b"Password  : ")
    tn.write(password.encode('ascii') + b"\n")
tn.write("tcpip\n")
tn.write("exit\n")
print(tn.read_all())
```

manually i am able to login into the device, pasted the login screen of the device below for more clarity

User Name : apc
Password  : ***

### Schneider Electric                      Network Management Card AOS      v6.4.6

Name      : apcE2FA28                                 Date : 09/05/2018
Contact   : Unknown                                   Time : 21:56:52
Location  : Unknown                                   User : Super User
Up Time   : 0 Days 0 Hours 7 Minutes                  Stat : P+ N4+ N6+ A+

Type ? for command listing
Use tcpip command for IP address(-i), subnet(-s), and gateway(-g)

apc>tcpip
E000: Success

### Active IPv4 Settings

Active IPv4 Address:          192.168.8.8
  Active IPv4 Subnet Mask:      255.255.255.0
  Active IPv4 Gateway:          0.0.0.0

### Manually Configured IPv4 Settings

IPv4:                 enabled
  Manual Settings:      enabled

IPv4 Address:         192.168.8.8
  Subnet Mask:          255.255.255.0
  Gateway:              0.0.0.0
  MAC Address:          00 C0 B7 E2 FA 28
  Domain Name:          example.com
  Host Name:            apcE2FA28

apc>

Comment: On which terminal are you launching the script? Is it from an IDE? I believe `getpass` tries to be "secure" so instead of reading the password from stdin [it looks for the `tty`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/getpass.html). This will generally not work when launching the script inside an IDE.If you open a proper terminal window and launch the script there are you still unable to insert the password?

Comment: Launched the script in Pycharm IDE as well as windows terminal in both the cases i am unable to insert the password. Manually i am able to login into the network power switch from windows terminal